# Issues Connecting to MongoDB using JMeters JSR223

Tags: mongodb, jmeter, performance-testing, database-performance, jsr223

I'm a college senior doing my capstone project. In this project, **I create 2 databases using MySQL & on MongoDB. The basis of my project is to see which database queries housing data most efficiently. **

I'm using **JMeter to perform the testing.**
Connecting and Querying on MySQL's DB was straightforward through Jmeter.

MongoDB... not so much.

I have removed an old MongoDB Driver Jar file from JMeters Lib & I have added the following Jar files:

bson-4.9.1.jar
groovy-4.0.11.jar
mongo-java-driver-3.12.13.jar

(I have tried downloading the most up-to-date Mongodb jar files using Gradle but, was not successful... all the files I've downloaded come from mvn repository site.https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver)

I am using MongoDB's connection string code from their site (the image is below) to try and connect

[Connection String From Mongo DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s28ST.png)

[Connection String code in JMeter provided by MongoDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRF71.png)

[Error Trying to connect MongoDB to JMeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyQNZ.png)

I expected the connection string provided by MongoDB to instantly connect JMeter and MongoDB together.

I don't if I should mention that I am not running MongoDB locally on my computer. I am using Mongo's Atlas service that hosts my database through the web

Answer (score 0):

You're copying and pasting incompatible configurations and pieces of code.

If you want to use [MongoDB 4.3](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-java-driver-4-3-0-released/115086) you need to follow the [official instructions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/v4.3/quick-start/) on driver installation.

The error you're getting means that you don't have [mongodb-driver-core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-core) .jar in your [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

The minimal set of .jar files should look like:

- bson-4.3.4.jar
- mongodb-driver-core-4.3.4.jar
- mongodb-driver-sync-4.3.4.jar

drop them to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation and restart JMeter to pick them up. Once done the code should start working (or at least ClassNotFound error will go away)

There is no need to download Groovy library as [JMeter comes with Groovy](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/gradle.properties#L92).

More information: [MongoDB Performance Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance)

Comment: I have no prior experience writing in Groovy or Java. Do you know what the code to connect to my MongoDB would look like? 

I’ve seen snippets of people’s code if they’re connecting from their local machine but, I haven’t seen code from someone connecting via Mongos Atlas services.

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to achieve. My expectation is that you need to use the same code that your real application would use, the same Mongo Java client driver version, sync or async, the same thread pool, etc. Groovy language documentation for version 3.0.11: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-3.0.11/html/. More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy). The code might differ for different versions of Mongo Java client, I don't know which one you should be using hence cannot provide it.